# Access denied for user 'root'@'172.19.0.2' (using password: YES) (Docker for windows)

Tags: docker, mariadb

I'm trying to run a docker container but I get this error:

```
2022-12-21 22:49:28 Running Rboxlo on port 80
2022-12-21 22:49:28 SqlError: (conn=6, no: 1045, SQLState: 28000) Access denied for user 'root'@'172.19.0.2' (using password: YES)
2022-12-21 22:49:28   text: "(conn=6, no: 1045, SQLState: 28000) Access denied for user 'root'@'172.19.0.2' (using password: YES)",
2022-12-21 22:49:28   sql: null,
2022-12-21 22:49:28   fatal: true,
2022-12-21 22:49:28   errno: 1045,
2022-12-21 22:49:28   sqlState: '28000',
2022-12-21 22:49:28   code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR'
2022-12-21 22:49:28 }
```

I searched a lot for this error, but all the answers I could find do not fix the error

.env file:

`# Database  DB_PASSWORD=passhere DB_USERNAME=root DB_NAME=rboxlo`

i already created database in phpmyadmin

What did you try and what did you expect?

this app has a registration website but as docker cannot enter the database, the registration page would be infinite loading

[docker containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMNaw.png)